# VBA Microsoft Project Professional 2016: How do I read Actual Hours and Work (Hours) by task by resource by day date?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am simply trying to extract Actual and Work Hours data per day for each Task and Resource?

I can get one value (Work Hours) daily, but how do I get all the data I need per day?

Example:

10/2/2021, Tell Jokes, Rod Gilbert, 4, 4

10/2/2021, Tell Jokes, Michael McIntyre, 2, 4

Comment: It's not clear in your question exactly what we're looking at. In the examples, are those text strings in a single cell or over multiple cells? Which number is the actual hours and which are the work hours?  What is the formula you used to get the work hours?  Hint:  it's highly probably you need to combine `FIND` and `MID` to extract the part of the string you want.

Comment: Hi PeterT, thank you your comment. The Example shows the example data I am looking for from the plan. So Date, Task, Resource, ActualHoure, WorkHours. The only examples I could find wxtracted TimePhasedData for wither Task or Resource. I want Task and Resource. After looking up and down the data available and thinking Object Oriented, I found the answer I was looking for. See the answer. Please feel free to add more comments here. Ta Stew

Answer (score 0):

```
Set tsvs = ActiveProject.Tasks(T.ID).Resources(R.ID).TimeScaleData( _
        StartDate:=ActiveProject.ProjectStart, _
      EndDate:=ActiveProject.ProjectFinish, _
      Type:=pjResourceTimescaledWork, _
      TimeScaleUnit:=pjTimescaleDays, Count:=1)
```

Loop for T then R.
Obviously, this example pulls all tasks for a project.
I am still refining what I want but this answers my question.